# App Has Stopped While I Add Nav Controller

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I have a problem while i run app, no coding error but the app has stopped while i run. Maybe like this.

2022-05-23 21:49:21.065 29057-29057/org.d3if0063.garbageanywhere E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: org.d3if0063.garbageanywhere, PID: 29057
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.d3if0063.garbageanywhere/org.d3if0063.garbageanywhere.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity org.d3if0063.garbageanywhere.MainActivity@c36f0b5 does not have a NavController set on 2131362096
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity org.d3if0063.garbageanywhere.MainActivity@c36f0b5 does not have a NavController set on 2131362096
at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.kt:50)
at androidx.navigation.ActivityKt.findNavController(Activity.kt:31)
at org.d3if0063.garbageanywhere.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:26)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

Comment: show us the code

Comment: @Prabu check your code anywhere you're using this `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView` layout in your XML. Check out the whole layout and tell me where you are using this layout.